# Interleaving bytes

Tags: digital-logic, digital-communications

Can someone explain how exactly interleaving is done? Is there a way to do it?

From what I understood, interleaving is transmitting only some bits of a byte for transmission, but did not exactly understand what bits are transmitted, and how are they selected.

Comment: Can you give us more information. What is the context? The word 'interleaving' can mean different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of communications systems (also digital recording systems such as disk and tape), interleaving is sometimes used to deal with "burst" errors, where a relatively large group of adjacent bits/bytes can be corrupted, but there are also long stretches of uncorrupted data.

Interleaving simply means breaking a single transmission unit up into smaller pieces, and spreading those pieces out in time by sequencing them with pieces from other transmission units. For example, if the transmission unit is a byte or word, you might interleave its bits with several other words. If the transmission unit is a block or packet, you might interleave its bytes with bytes from other blocks/packets.

Interleaving is often associated with a FEC (forward error correction) scheme of some sort, and it makes the FEC algorithm better able to deal with burst errors, by spreading the effects of those errors over multiple transmission units.

Comment: Certainly having error-detecting codes operate on separated pieces of data can be helpful, but one needn't interleave actual data for that.  If one wanted to record N*256 bytes on a cassette tape, one could record all the data as is in blocks with 32-bit CRCs, and then record a block which was the XOR of all the even-numbered ones, and one that was the XOR of all the odd-numbered ones.  Any bad spot smaller than a block could thus be corrected, but all of the "real" data would be stored in order.

Comment: The primary use I'm familiar with for interleaving actual data is designed around the assumption that one will be interested in a fraction of the data which is transmitted; interleaving chunks of data one is interested in with chunks that are not of interest will allow the recipient time to process each "interesting" chunk before the next interesting chunk arrives.

Comment: I was indeed talking about interleaving in digital communications and FEC, but how do you interleave them? Is there a set algorithm/way to do it, or there are many different ways of doing it?

Comment: If you're implementing a standard protocol, it will be part of the protocol specification. If you're inventing your own protocol, you can do it any way you like, as long as both ends are doing it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain how exactly interleaving is done? Is there a way
>   to do it?

From my experience (in telemetry systems) where you want to get a hundred bytes of data from a hundred sensors (attached to a machine) AND you want to sample ALL the sensors at one instant, interleaving is the easiest practical way to transmit the all data through a serial link.

All one-hundred ADCs are set to convert and the data from each is clocked out serially on each into what I can only describe as a 100:1 multiplexer. In effect all one-hundred MSBs are sent first followed by the next bit until all one hundred LSBs are transmitted. Then the process starts again after a header byte is transmitted.

If you didn't have to sample the ADCs together, you could transmit all the  bits of sensor 1 then sensor 2 etc. but this isn't interleaving in my book.

So, the way I do it is have a big multiplexer in an FPGA or PLD. In fact, the signals are multiplexed in groups of 12 and then the composite serial streams are multiplexed again but the principle is the same.

Adding to Dave Tweed's answer about interleaving to improve the chances of correcting errors - I've seen this used over radio systems - the error correction algorithm is good at detecting 1 or 2 bits per byte and because radio suffers from block interference it would likely take out 1 or more bytes completely so spacing the bits (by interleaving) gives a better chance of correcting block interference problems.

Answer (score 0):

Interleaving in a digital communication system is done when using Error Correcting codes. It is done in the following situations:

1. While using a Linear Block Code which has no memory units in the encoder and which is usually decoded using Syndrome decoding. In this case, assume that the input to the Encoder are symbols of size k bits and the block code produces an output of size n bits(n>k). Several output symbols of n bits are taken together and stored as rows(or columns) in a memory array, this is where the latency factor comes in. There should be as many number of rows (or columns) to combat the Coherence Time of the fade (in terms of symbols of course) and then the data is output by reading the array column-wise (or row wise). This will help protect all the code symbols against fade burst because no individual symbol will be entirely affected by a deep fade. I've explained using bits, one can easily extrapolate the same to codes that operate on symbols. Basically what we need is that a single codeword should be spread across the entire period of transmission of several symbols so that all the symbols can be decoded "reliably". For this to be done successfully, one needs to know the channel statistics.
2. The other case where interleaving is done is within the Encoder itself, in case of concatenated codes i.e. Turbo codes which requires a little bit more of a technical detail to explain which you can look up if you want to. But essentially the concept is the same. Here, interleaving is inherent in the Encoder itself and burst errors can be corrected by the use of Iterative Decoding.

> From what i understood, interleaving is transmitting only some bits of a byte for transmission

Well, it looks like what you read is actually known as "Puncturing" in the case of Error correcting codes and this is not related to interleaving in any way. Puncturing is done in case the channel seems to be really good (if you have  a good SNR). The receiver can assume the symbols that were not sent by the Transmitter to be any value and still decode to the correct codeword, essentially the receiver assumes that the channel statistics are really good and it is not going to receive (on an average) too many errors that it cannot correct.